# How to insert date and time in vim along with string literal?

Tags: vim, vi

I'm new to `Vim` and trying to solve what might just be a very basic thing.

When I type `dd` and press `<space>` in `insert` mode, I want it to be replaced with `[10-Feb-2011 10:10]`. (notice the square brackets around date).

So, far I've been able to achieve this - `:iab <expr> dd strftime("%e-%b-%Y %H:%M")` which inserts date, but I also want it to be surrounded by square brackets.

I'm using *Maemo's* implementation of *Vim* on *Nokia N900*.

http://maemo.org/downloads/product/Maemo5/vim/

I'd also like to know how to make this change persistent so that the `dd` abbreviation is always available in all sessions of vim. (writing this line in `~/.vim` or something like this).

Comment: Two small things, you probably mean Vim instead of Vi, and you probably mean "insert mode" instead of "edit mode".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your ~/.vimrc file:

```
:iab <expr> dd strftime("[%e-%b-%Y %H:%M]")
```

Note however that Vim uses your platform's `strftime` so the string it takes and the format flags in particular are platform-dependent.

Comment: Run `man 3 strftime` to get help on `strftime`. Delete the space after `<expr>` if you want `dd` to work at the beginning of a line.